# sorting arrays by months

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array sort function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697759/array-sort-function-in-php)

I have an array like so

```
Array
(
[May] => 10904
[Jan] => 9269
[Jun] => 3743
[Feb] => 3507
[Mar] => 6017
[Apr] => 4966
)
```

How can I sort them by months. Jan, Feb, Mar, etc...

I tried this with no luck.

```
$ytdCommissions = array_flip($ytdCommissions);

usort($ytdCommissions,'monthCompare');
function monthCompare($a, $b)
{
    $months = array('JAN' => 1, 'FEB' =>2,'MAR' => 3,'APR' => 4,'MAY' => 5,'JUN' => 6,'JULY' => 7,'AUG' => 8, 'SEP' => 9, 'OCT' => 10, 'NOV' => 11, 'DEC' => 12);
    if($a == $b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($months[$a] > $months[$b]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an associative array, there's really no need to sort it. You can just iterate through using your keys in order.

Comment: As Will said, you don't need to sort it. Other than creating a new function you can create a new array having the month's sorted and then do a merge. Whatever your solution - it should be O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) you need to use `uksort` as you're sorting keys

2.) you should compare uppercase-keys in order to match your month-array:

```
$a = strtoupper($a);
$b = strtoupper($b);
```

Comment: Your solution is more elegant than mine +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
    'May' => 10904,
    'Jan' => 9269,
    'Jun' => 3743,
    'Feb' => 3507,
    'Mar' => 6017,
    'Apr' => 4966,
);

$sort = array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');

uksort($data,
       function($value1, $value2) use ($sort) {
           return array_search($value1,$sort) > array_search($value2,$sort);
       }
);

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an array of months like so:

```
$months = array("Jan", "Feb", "March", "etc...");
```

Then for each month assign them whatever values you like:

```
$months[0] = 9269; // Jan
$months[2] = 6017; // March
```

Then the months are just the keys of the `$months` array, `$months[0]` being **January** and `$months[11]` being **December**.

Answer (score 0):

You were sorting with sort which is for values. Should have used uksort. Also removed the array you built as I thought it was superfluous:

```
$arr = array(
"May" => 10904,
"Jan" => 9269,
"Jun" => 3743,
"Feb" => 3507,
"Mar" => 6017,
"Apr" => 4966,
);

uksort($arr,'monthCompare');

var_dump($arr);

function monthCompare($a, $b)
{
    //$months = array('JAN' => 1, 'FEB' =>2,'MAR' => 3,'APR' => 4,'MAY' => 5,'JUN' => 6,'JULY' => 7,'AUG' => 8, 'SEP' => 9, 'OCT' => 10, 'NOV' => 11, 'DEC' => 12);
    $aMonth = date("m", strtotime($a));
    $bMonth = date("m", strtotime($b));

    if($a == $b)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($aMonth > $bMonth) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function monthCompare($a, $b)
{
    $months = array('JAN' => 1, 'FEB' =>2,'MAR' => 3,'APR' => 4,'MAY' => 5,'JUN' => 6,'JULY' => 7,'AUG' => 8, 'SEP' => 9, 'OCT' => 10, 'NOV' => 11, 'DEC' => 12);
    if($a[0] == $b[0])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($months[$a[0]] > $months[$b[0]]) ? 1 : -1;

}


$ytdCommissions = array(
 array('MAY' , 10904),
 array('JAN' , 9269),
 array('JUN' , 3743),
 array('FEB' , 3507),
 array('MAR' , 6017),
 array('APR' , 4966)
);

usort($ytdCommissions,'monthCompare');
print_r($ytdCommissions);
```

- You use capital letters in `$months`: `JAN` vs. `Jan` on `$ytdCommissions`
- The array `$ytdCommissions` is not build correctly for using usort - check out my example above

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying but there seems to be no other way.

Here's the shortest code I could work out:

```
<?
$months[May] = 10904;
$months[Jan] = 9269;
$months[Jun] = 3743;
$months[Feb] = 3507;
$months[Mar] = 6017;
$months[Apr] = 4966;

for($m=1;$m<=12;$m++)
{
    $m_index[date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,2000))] = $m;
}

foreach($months as $i => $v)
{
    $months_out[$m_index[$i]] = $v;
}
ksort($months_out);
print_r($months_out);
?>
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [1] => 9269
    [2] => 3507
    [3] => 6017
    [4] => 4966
    [5] => 10904
    [6] => 3743
)
```