# PHP re-order array of month names(associative array)

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to reorder an associative array which has label value pairs.I am getting the label data aligned in alphabetical order.but i need the array to be ordered in the form of array of months.
My input looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => August
            [value] => 100.55
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => November
            [value] => 100.24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => October
            [value] => 99.19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => September
            [value] => 100.11
        )

)
```

output:
In the output array i need the arrays to be ordered as August,September,October,November.Any suggestions please

Comment: @u_mulder, this is not a duplicate of the question you've provided.

Comment: You can use array_shift(). Please check the answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936309/php-rearrange-array-by-specific-index

Comment: Let suppose your array is $original_array.Then use this code    <?php
$months=array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
$result=array();
foreach($original_array as $key=>$val){
    if($key=array_search($val['label'], $months)){
        $result[$key]=array('label'=>$val['label'],'value'=>$val['value']);
    }
}
ksort($result);
print_r($result);

?>

Comment: @u_mulder this question is not a duplicate, please re-open

Comment: __NO__, I will not reopen this question. And yes, it is a __duplicate__. OP shows no effort in researching the task, so the dupe is a point to start with.

Comment: @u_mulder If you insist, it should be a duplicate of this: [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597736/134824])

Comment: This is just another duplicate. __EVERYTHING__ is described in a previous dupe. Case closed.

Comment: I'll add to the pile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697759/array-sort-function-in-php/5697788#5697788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make order array and then sort by usort functon

```
$seq = array_flip([ 'August', 'September', 'October',  'November' ]);

usort($arr, function ($i1, $i2) use($seq) { return $seq[$i1['label']] - $seq[$i2['label']]; });
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/908868)